# how to prevent loss of sign in Arithmetic Shift Left (ASL)

Tags: math, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

During Arithmetic Shift Right (ASR), the MSB gets copied to the left, so the sign remains - that's clear. However in Arithmetic Shift Left (ASL), the sign could be in some cases lost, e.g.

```
01001001 << 1 = 10010010
```

The original number was obviously positive since the MSB was 0, but the shifted number is negative since the MSB is 1. Could you please explain why this is?

Comment: How do you expect to represent the number 148 as an 8-bit signed integer? "I have a bag that can hold up to ten pounds of rocks. It currently has eight pounds of rocks. How can I double the number of rocks in the bag without breaking it?"

Comment: Have you read this yet? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift

Comment: @Raymond, it was a typo!

Comment: @Robert, yes, but it was not clear for me. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Even with the fixed typo, the problem still exists. The starting number is 01001001 = 73 decimal. The shifted value is 10010010 = 146 decimal. How do you expect to put 146 inside an 8-bit signed integer? The range of an 8-bit signed integer is -128...+127.

Comment: The numbers are signed, so the values are in 7 bits represented. `01001001 = +73` and `10010010 = -110` in two's complement. If it was unsigned it would be 146! Let me know, if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike with right shifts, there isn't really an "arithmetic left shift" to contrast with a "logical left shift", there is only one kind of left shift, and it discards the sign.

There is nothing else it can do, really. Those cases where a left shift changes the sign, are precisely those cases in which the "real result" would not be expressible in however many bits you have.

Answer (score 0):

For two's complement binary values the left shift that causes a negative value to become positive is just a rollover condition. The result of the operation is an overflow. Use a larger integer type. If you are using a one's complement representation then convert it to a two's complement value first then do the shift and convert it back.

Comment: ok thanks to all for clarification and advise. So I didn't missunderstand it

Answer (score 0):

In "Arithmetic Shift Left", using signed values (of any bit-value size (8, 16, etc.)), which is just a logical shift left (multiply by 2), it will give you a correct result EXCEPT any time the MSB changes (1=>0 or 0=>1) it is an overflow (/underflow) or error (undefined result) condition.

There are/were some processors that have an overflow or error flag that would be set for you to test, otherwise you have to do the test yourself programmatically.

For unsigned values, any time the Carry bit is set after the shift, it is an overflow. (be careful with any left shift instructions that do not shift INTO the carry and just drop the MSB)